# Android Sqlite Syntax Error while reading rows

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax

I've got simple android app that connects to my server and saves table to database and shows needed row of database with button click.
The problem is whenever I want to reach my rows by using "date" column it throws that exception below.
Well, If i call row by id everything works correct.

My question is that is because of dots of date variable or something else ? 
 Note: I have looked to database with opener programs and everything looks fine but i can`t read rows with android using date column.

this is my exception is

```
    02-09 19:45:21.909: E/AndroidRuntime(8286): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
 near ".2014": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, Date, Day, v1, v2, v3, 
v4 FROM db1 WHERE Date=07.02.2014
```

my Create Sql command

```
DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DbTableName + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_Date
                + " text not null, " + KEY_Day + " text not null, " + KEY_v1
                + " text not null, " + KEY_v2 + " text not null, " + KEY_v3
                + " text not null, " + KEY_v4 + " text not null "
                + ");";
```

my get method

```
public Cursor getDay(String date) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_Date, KEY_Day, KEY_v1, KEY_v2, KEY_v3, KEY_v4 },
                KEY_Date + "=" + date, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your string literals with `''` or use `?` placeholders. That is, either change

```
KEY_Date + "=" + date,
```

to

```
KEY_Date + "='" + date + "'"
```

or even better, change

```
KEY_Date + "=" + date, null
```

to

```
KEY_Date + "=?", new String[] { date }
```

Comment: is it about sqlinjection issue ?

Comment: Yes, the `?` bind arg method prevents syntax problems and SQL injections, and in some cases, improves performance. But the original problem was just that the string literal was not quoted.

Comment: well, this was what i thought in a first place. Thank you for your solution.